# Specific Character Pattern Python

Tags: python

I am trying to achieve the following;

Write a program that produces the following output giving an integer input n.

The result should be the following;

```
n=1     n=2     n=3         n=4
+       A+B     AA+BB       AAA+BBB
        +E+     A+E+B       AA+E+BB
        C+D     +EEE+       A+EEE+B
                C+E+D       +EEEEE+
                CC+DD       C+EEE+D 
                            CC+E+DD
                            CCC+DDD
```

I am having issues solving this problem.

When I enter 2 I am currently getting the following but unable how to make it look like the above.

Current result;

```
A+
B+
E+
C+
D
```

Here is my code;

```
 def specific_pattern(n):
    addition = "+"
    alp = "A, B, E, C, D"
    # myList = ["A, B, C, D, E"]
    newList = []
    for j in range(0, n):
        for i in range(0, j):
            if n == 1:
                print(addition)
            else:
                letters = alp.split(", ")
                for letter in range(len(letters)):
                    newList.append(letters[letter]*j+addition)
                newchar = "".join(newList)
                print(newchar[:-1])

n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
specific_pattern(n)
```

Comment: You will need to provide more clarity on the logic behind the alphabets and the sequences, and how it is related to n.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple iteration to create both the top and bottom of the desired diamond:

```
def sequence(d):
   c, l = 0, 1
   while c < d - 1:
     if l%2:
       yield l
       c += 1
     l += 1

def make_pattern(d):
   t, b, r = f'{"A"*(d-1)}+{"B"*(d-1)}', f'{"C"*(d-1)}+{"D"*(d-1)}', list(sequence(d))
   body = '\n'.join(f'{"A"*((r[-1]-i)//2)}+{"E"*i}+{"B"*((r[-1]-i)//2)}' for i in r[:-1]) + \
     f'\n+{"E"*r[-1]}+\n'+'\n'.join(f'{"C"*((r[-1]-i)//2)}+{"E"*i}+{"D"*((r[-1]-i)//2)}' for i in r[:-1][::-1])
   return f'{t}\n{body}\n{b}'

def diamond(d):
  return {1:lambda _:'+', 2:lambda _:'A+B\n+E+\nC+D'}.get(d, make_pattern)(d)

print(diamond(3))
print('-'*5)
print(diamond(4))
```

Output:

```
AA+BB
A+E+B
+EEE+
C+E+D
CC+DD
-----
AAA+BBB
AA+E+BB
A+EEE+B
+EEEEE+
C+EEE+D
CC+E+DD
CCC+DDD
```

Comment: Hi Ajax, is it possible if you're able to explain `make_pattern()` function and `diamond()` function? I am a bit overwhelmed with trying to understand them.